# Microsoft teams graph API(Joined team) is returning empty teams result

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

When accessing the joined Teams of a user(user is registered as a guest in AAD). The Microsoft Teams Graph API([Joined team](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_joinedteams)) is returning an empty result. So it would be great if any feedback/help on it is available.

**What is achieved till now**

1. Able to generate the access token using [secret key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) approach by using the admin app registration. all the request are sent using Postman
2. Able to fetch all user(registered guests in AAD) of AAD using the access token.

Note: I have added the guest users in newly created directory, as I want to keep the users in a separate directory for B2B implementation.

**Actual results**

Here is the  request of [Joined team](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_joinedteams) api. Here `8848b4c4-c89f-4d21-95e8-c19fa9024786` is the Id of user.

Request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/8848b4c4-c89f-4d21-95e8-c19fa9024786/joinedTeams
```

Response :

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#groups",
    "value": []
}
```

**Expected Result**

Should be able to get the list of joined teams using this API

Comment: Do you see the correct group using [`memberOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0)?

Comment: Please verify if user is actually part of any of the groups as requested by Marc. When using [delegated permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) you need to [specify TenantId instead of common as explained in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/troubleshoot/faq#teams-apps-and-authentication-with-guest-users-and-microsoft-teams-free).